# Changing Values in form.php

Tags: mpdf

Using mpdf to generate pdf as activeform.
In this case the class form.php is called.
Is there another way to change values in the form class than to change the source?
F.e. want to change form_element_spacing['input']['outer']['h'] or form_button_border_width

I am doing this currently in the source code.

Any other way?

Best regards,
Jürgen

Comment: You could add a form to your page and read variables from the request to change these values

Comment: Hi Nico, thx for answer, but do not know what you mean with adding a form. My html page does have a form of course and I generate the pdf using mpdf class and parameter useActiveForms = true to generate the pdf which is fillable.
Can you give me an examle of what you are talking about?
BR Jürgen

Comment: Hi Nico,
I tried to set the values with the following code:
            $mpdf = new  \Mpdf\Mpdf();
            $mpdf->useActiveForms = true;
            $mpdf->form->form_element_spacing['input']['outer']['h'] = 2.5;
But this is not working because $form is defined as private in Mpdf class.
If I set this to public it is working and I can change the values in the Form class as I want it.
Is this a correct way even if I had to change the Mpdf class?
Or do you have another solution for this?
BR Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using the latest version of mPDF (7.x) as it looks like that functionality has been removed / potential bug.

Current options:

1. Downgrade to 6.1.
2. Set the $form variable in `mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php` to `public`
3. Edit the values directly in `mpdf/mpdf/src/Form.php`.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for this.
I choosed point 2, because it is the easiest way.
Best regards
Jürgen